# Something wrong table-cell-like div display

Tags: jquery, css, html

im trying to make a web-design based on the old table-rows-cells idea. I read I can use `display: table` / `table-row` / `table-cell`. The problem is when I´m using sortable library, bad things happens:

```
.bloque {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

```
<div class='bloque'>
</div>
<div class='bloque'>
</div>
```

Full example working:
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dX6UR/1/)

If I move one list element inside of the block, the div (suppose to be independent) with class `bloque` in the right is moving too :S. In the fiddle you can see it. What can i do?

Comment: One does not simply curse on SO

Comment: `</div> <ul class="elementos"></ul> </div>`, what kind of markup is this?????

Comment: @ManofSnow : couldn't get a more formal substitute!! :D

Comment: @OP : rephrase your question, m not getting your problem!!

Comment: Look at jsfiddle link, there it is the example working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try add

```
 .bloque {
         vertical-align: top;
  }
```

[CHECK ON FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dX6UR/3/)